# In a square, similarity of triangles obtained by joining a vertex to a midpoint

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, centroid, geometric-transformation

The problem states: $ABCD$ is a square with side $a$. $E$ and $F$ are considered midpoints of sides $AD$ and $AB$
respectively. Let $G$ be the point of intersection of the $EC$ and $DF$ segments. Show that the $\triangle EGD$ and $\triangle DCE$ are similar and deduce that $DG\perp EC$.

[image: image of problem]

---

I've tried to prove that $\triangle EDG~\triangle DCE$ using the $AA$ postulate. I made $\angle ECD=α$, then $\angle CED=90°-α$. After that, I used angle properties like alternate interior angles and others all over the figure in the hopes of getting $\angle EDG$ to equal $90°$ in order to show perpendicularity. However, I was unsuccessful in all my attempts. Any idea on how I could solve this?

P.D.: I don't want a solution, just some guidance to solve this myself.

Comment: The similarity sign `~` didn't came between $\triangle EDG$ and $DCE$.

Comment: First you can use vectors to prove the perpendicularity and then use similarity in right triangle to prove the other results.

Comment: I want to note that vectors approach fits perfectly fine for this problem, although it's not needed: $\overrightarrow{CE}\cdot\overrightarrow{DF}=(\overrightarrow{CD}+\overrightarrow{DE})\cdot(\overrightarrow{DA}+\overrightarrow{AF})=$
$(\overrightarrow{CD}+\frac12\overrightarrow{DA})\cdot(\overrightarrow{DA}+\frac12\overrightarrow{AB})=$ $0+\frac12DA^2-\frac12AB^2+0=0$ as $|DA|=|AB|$

Comment: What about the barycenter in the title? There is no reference in the body of the question

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title into something more significant (In particular by suppressing the term "barycenter"), more likely to be "hit" by further searches.

Answer (score 2):

Triangles $DCE$ and $ADF$ are congruent by side-angle-side, showing $\angle EDG = \angle DCE$ and results follow.

Answer (score 1):

An other hint that shows directly the perpendicularity. Let $O$ be the (symmetry) center of the square, and consider a $90^\circ$-rotation centered in $O$, which brings $C\to D$, $D\to A$, $A\to B$, $B\to C$, thus also the mid points of segments one to another, $E\to F$. The lines $CE$ and $EF$ are thus mapped one into the other one by a $90^\circ$ rotation, so they are perpendicular. (These are a lot of sentences, but the idea is optically seen at a glance.)

Comment: nice ...+1..........